# Uncaught Error when the project is in the 'htdocs' folder

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, php-7

I created a composer project with the intention of testing out MongoDB and PHP (all extensions have been loaded into the project)

Here is my sample `composer.json` project:

```
{
    "name": "user/project-name",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.4"
    }
}
```

Inside the root, I created an `index.php` file with the following:

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
// Rest of the project comes here. Doesn't matter because this is the point of failure
```

If I place the project the `htdocs` folder (using XAMPP), I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project-name/index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project-name/index.php on line 4
```

If I run it with the PHP server (`php -S localhost:8000`), however, it works fine:

Could there be a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using the same php version? Have you checked that the extension is active in xampp's php?

Comment: Yes I have, and the extension is active in XAMPP's PHP

Comment: It turns out you were right

Answer (score 0):

From [ku-chan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386528/kuh-chan), it turns out MacOS High Sierra comes with a PHP version, which is used when you are running the `php` command from the terminal. This had the correct extensions installed and the PHP version that came with XAMPP did not.